# Call for value in corresponding MYSQL Table in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following simple search code:

```
 <?php

mysql_connect ("localhost", "xxx","xxx")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("xxx");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from attendees where Surname like '%$term%' or Name like'%$term%' ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<br/> Name: '.$row['Name'];
echo '<br/> Last Name: '.$row['Surname'];
echo '<br/> E-Mail: '.$row['email'];
echo '<br/><br/>';
}
?>
```

This works fine and displays the requested data from the attendees table, however I want to also display an image with each result. The problem here is the path to the image is in the table "images" in the column "path". The column id_attendees in the attendees table and the column id_images in the images table are the same, so if id_attendees is 4 for example the row with id_images=4 contains the imagepath in the column "path" . So how do I call for this path here?

Comment: Your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection! Look into [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

use left join

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from attendees a
                       left join images i on a.id_attendees = i.id_images
                       where a.Surname like '%$term%' or a.Name like'%$term%' ");
```

this will join attendes with images and left join make sure if there is no id that is matching the attendes then it displays null for images....

and as everyone here in stackoverflow recommends...even i  recommend you to use mysqli
since

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the use of mysql_* functions is highly discouraged.

Anyway; you can write this with a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT whatever, you, want
FROM attendees JOIN id_attendees = id_images
WHERE ... your current where clause
```

and you can just use all the columns you want (as long as you select them), like you do now:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<br/> Name: '.$row['Name'];
echo '<br/> Last Name: '.$row['Surname'];
echo '<br/> E-Mail: '.$row['email'];

echo '<img src="'.$row['image_path'].'" />'; // YOUR IMAGE

echo '<br/><br/>';
}
```

***Note:*** Your code is using *mysql_* functions, which is discouraged. Also note that you have high SQL Injection vulnerability in your current code. Use mysql_real_escape_string to make sure your data is escaped, or better, use PDO or something the correct way to prevent this and have the benefits of a good system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN` for joining the images table for getting the image path

```
mysql_connect ("localhost", "xxx","xxx")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("xxx");

// Note that you have to escape your search term to prevent SQL Injection
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['term']);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT a.*, i.imagepath 
                    FROM attendees a 
                    JOIN images i
                      ON i.id_images=a.id_attendees
                    WHERE a.Surname LIKE '%$term%' OR a.Name LIKE '%$term%' ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo '<br/> Name: '.$row['Name'];
  echo '<br/> Last Name: '.$row['Surname'];
  echo '<br/> E-Mail: '.$row['email'];
  echo '<br/><br/>';
}
```

**You have to use MySQLi or PDO because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated!**

Answer (score 0):

always use joints when it comes to linking tables, in your situation it will be like :

```
$query = "select a.*, i.path
          from attendees a
             inner join images i ON i.id_images = a.id_attendees
          where a.Surname like '%$term%' or a.Name like'%$term%'"
```

for further understanding on this, check this out http://phpweby.com/tutorials/mysql/32

Comment: only use inner joints if there is a value in the other table, else no row will be returned, if your not sure that there is a row, use left or right joints

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_connect ("localhost", "xxx","xxx") or die (mysql_error());<p>
mysql_select_db ("xxx");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM attendees t1 LEFT JOIN images t2 ON t1.id_attendees=t2.id_images WHERE t1.Surname LIKE '%$term%' OR t1.Name LIKE'%$term%' ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<br/> Name: '.$row['Name'];
echo '<br/> Last Name: '.$row['Surname'];
echo '<br/> E-Mail: '.$row['email'];
echo '<br/> Image: <img alt="img" src="' . $row['path'] . '">';
echo '<br/><br/>';

}
```